# Jquery Increasing the value of CSS property in a object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-grid

I'm experimenting with CSS Grid and jQuery and I'm stuck here. I'm trying to expand the box in the direction of my arrow key, I can print the `console.log` but it doesn't update the `grid-column-start` value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    console.log(("Key: " + event.which));
  });

  const box = {
    leftSide: $('.boxA').css('grid-column-start'),
    rightSide: $('.boxA').css('grid-column-end'),
    topSide: $('.boxA').css('grid-row-start'),
    bottomSide: $('.boxA').css('grid-row-start'),

    moveLeft: function() {
      if (this.leftSide > 1) {
        console.log(this.leftSide);
        $('.boxA').css('grid-row-start', function() {
          return box.leftSide - 1;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37:
        box.moveLeft();
        break;

      case 38: // up
        break;

      case 39: // right
        break;

      case 40: // down
        break;

      default:
        return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
  });
});
```

```css
.mediumboxes {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 5%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 10%);
}

.boxA {
  display: block;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background-color: red;
}

.boxB {
  display: block;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 11;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to increase the value of `leftSide` without specifying again the whole DOM path `$('boxA').css('grid-column-start', box.leftSide - 1)` on the line 10.

Is it possible with only referring to `this.leftside`?

Comment: Do you need each instance of `.boxA` to have it's own values? Using `$('.boxA').css('grid-column-start')` will only return value of first matching element in the collection (if there are more than one)

Comment: @charlietfl no .boxA is a single elements with his own values
.boxA {
    display: block;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    background-color: red;
}

Comment: @Marco Can you please add HTML parts to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Just do `this.leftSide = this.leftSide - 1;`

Your code seems to be acting as if `leftSide` is a function. Assuming you change it to just being an assignment, there's nothing wrong with the code as it stands.

See here: http://jsbin.com/pacikas/2/edit?js,console

Comment: Please correct me of course if I've missed something in your question!

Comment: It doesn't work, it wont update the value in the DOM